# simple C program crashes when run

Tags: c

hi i'm having some trouble with my program when i run it it crashes and i have to force it closed and i'm having some trouble determining what's causing it any help will be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myprint(char let, int num, int line)
{
int countL=0,countT=0,numb, lin;
char abc;
numb=num;
line=lin;
abc=let;

while(countL<lin)
{
    while(countT<numb)
    {
        printf("%s",abc );
        countT++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    countL++;
 }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int times = 5, lines = 3;
char letter = 'a';

myprint(letter, times, lines);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger. It will help you locate the problem in no time. But I suggest you look more into the `printf` call inside the loop...

Comment: Or just compile with warnings.

Comment: I noticed you do not reset countT=0 after in the inner while loop is done. so the subsequent lines will have nothing in them. Not the source of your crash but still figured I would mention it.

Comment: The code uses obscure indention and there isn't much effort made by the poster. Why all the upvotes? What's so fantastic with yet another uninitialized variable bug?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that you have a single character and are trying to print it as a string:

```
printf("%s",abc );
```

In C strings are sequences of characters terminated by the null character `\0`. So this `printf` will attempt to keep printing characters until it finds that null byte. Your program probably keeps trying to read memory until it finds a bad segment, then it crashes.

What you may want to do instead is just specify a character in your `printf`:

```
printf("%c",abc );
```

---

Another problem is that you have the variables reversed in the assignment:

```
line=lin;
```

Answer (score 1):

`lin` has no initialized value.

I think the line that reads `line=lin;` should be `lin=line`

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting this initialization :

```
line=lin;
```

to

```
lin=line;
```

Otherwise, `lin` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s",abc );
```

prints a string, abc is a char.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

variable "lin" is not initialize properly,

line=lin;

so variable "line" and "lin" contains garbage value.

Problem 2:

change

printf("%s",abc );

to

printf("%c",abc );

as abc is a char.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `while(countL<lin)` loop you never reset the `countT` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
while(countT<numb)
{
    printf("%s",abc );
    countT++;
}
```

with

```
while(countT<numb)
{
    printf("%c",abc );
    countT++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `printf` incorrectly.

You passed `%s` as format, which requires `char*` as argument, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

THE ERROR IN YOUR CODE IS SIMPLE
"line=lin" is the problem of the code
here the variable lin is not initialised hence holds garbage value
this garbage value is passed on to the variable line and it screws up everything
i think the proper code would be lin=line
another bug i found was printf('%s',abc); the type specifier is wrong since abc has been declared as character and type specifier must be %c
I also found out that the unused command arguments args and argv  which can be only used to pass argument running from command promt